# Using image with hyperlink

Tags: java, birt

I am using BIRT API to design PDF.There I need to show an image with hyperlink for given URL. This image needs to have a URL hyperlinked and on image click given URL should open:

```
ImageHandle image = null;
image = factory.newImage(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
image.setFile((String) mediaImageMap.get(mediaType));
```

I am able to add image into PDF using ImageHandle but unable to link(hyperlinked) given URL with this image. Any suggestions?